# Fetching an image closest to the title description text of a url php

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I am trying to fetch the most relevant image from a url.
I want to fetch the image that is closest to the title 'text' of the page.
Or put it in a different way.
I want to give scores to images based on their distance from the the title 'text'.
And then fetch the image with the highest score.

The title 'text' could be in a heading element

```
<h1>title text</h1>,<h2>title text<h2>,etc
```

Or 
It may match up with the alt attribute of the

```
<img alt='title text'> tags.
```

Or
It may also be in any other element like

```
<p> , <span> , <div> etc
```

for eg:

Lets say the title of the page is as follows:

```
<title>White Gold Round Diamond Wedding Band: Jewelry: Amazon.com</title>
```

And in the body of the page we have something like:

```
<h1>White Gold Round Diamond Wedding Band</h1>
```

The  element closest to the above tag lets say is inside a div as follows:

```
<div class='abc'>
    <img src='efg' />
</div>
```

Then the above image should get the highest score.

Instead , if the img's alt attribute matches the title , then that image should get the highest score.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: -1 What have you tried? Or are you just posting requirements?

Comment: What is the question? How to measure string distance? (Google 'edit distance' and 'Levenshtein distance'.) How to calculate edit distance in PHP? How to measure the distance of images from a given heading?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen The closest is 'How to measure the distance of images from a given heading in php?'

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a good solution. 
Instead of this you can try getting `og:image` if it is set.

Another solution is to get all the images with `XPath` and get only those with a specified size, e.g.: bigger than `150px X 150px` and limited `width/height` ratio for example from `0.5` to `2`. If there are more than 1 image you can let the user choose one of them with a simple image slider just like on Facebook's share popups.

Also you can use something like [Embed.LY](http://embed.ly/) API, it works very accurately if you want to get some product images.

If you are working with Amazon and/or Ebay offers thoroughly, then you can try [Amazon's Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html) and [Ebay's Finding API](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByProduct.html) for best results. You just have to extract the offer ID from the given URL and send an API request to get the details for that offer, including the images with varied size.

And finally, best solution could be combining each method and use them like all-in-one.

Comment: This is a fallback solution to the first two cases you mentioned.
I have already written code to fetch the open graph og:image
and to fetch the largest image.
But even if that doest work, i felt this could be my last retort

Comment: Embed.ly is good but it has a limit of 10000 urls for the free plan :P

Comment: Its not just ebay or Amazon, it could be any product webstore and hence, any product url of such a store.